# How to add shape drawable as integer?

Tags: android, gridview, drawable, shapes

I have a calendar with a gridview, so filling the calendar with little blocks (days) looks like this:

```
adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year);
```

The R.id.calendar_day_gridcell is seperated in an xml file:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/calendar_day_gridcell"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="45dip"
        android:layout_height="45dip">
    </Button>
```

And the calendar_button_selector is another xml file:

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/calendar_bg_orange" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/calendar_bg_orange" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/grid_cell_sajat" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

At the grid_cell_sajat I have a shape with some gradient etc.. It works very well. How can I do these things programmatically?

```
 int colorsxx[] = { 0xff393939 , 0xffffffff };

        GradientDrawable g = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP, colorsxx);
        g.setStroke(3, Color.BLACK);
        GradientDrawable g2 = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, colorsxx);
        g2.setStroke(3, Color.BLACK);
        g.setBounds(10, 10, 10, 10);

        StateListDrawable stld = new StateListDrawable();
       stld.addState(new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_enabled},  g);
       stld.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed }, g2);

adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year);
```

Well 'stld' is a drawable, but the the adapter expects an integer. How can I set it for the adapter, or somehow convert it to "integer type"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try setting it as background ? Should work on most (all?) views. Using view.setBackground(R.drawable.calendar_button_selector);
I guess that calendar_button_selector would need to be in the drawable folder for that to work.

Comment: Im not sure about this 'view'. What should be added to the grdcell adaper int parameter?

Comment: well added as setBackgroundDrawable() works like charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad that it helped,
So answer was: Did you try setting it as background ? Should work on most (all?) views. Using view.setBackground(R.drawable.calendar_button_selector); I guess that calendar_button_selector would need to be in the drawable folder for that to work.